# How do I merge two quads that overlap each other into one?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am relatively new to Blender and since I couldn't find any answer elsewhere online I decided to ask here for some support.

How do I merge two faces into one? What I am trying to do is merge the left and right quads along the center together because they overlap and create two pieces that extrude instead of one (which is what I am trying to do)...

[image]

I tried Bridge-Edge Loop but it doesn't create the desired effect, as you can see here:

[image]

Thank you in advance!
Aldin

Comment: Can you add your [.blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) file?

Comment: @Photon: cegaton's answer solved the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have overlapping faces like this:

[image]

You can select the edges to be merged:

[image]

Then scale them to 0 on the X axis <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

[image]

and then press the space bar and type "remove doubles"

[image]